# How can I force SAS to wait for a command to fully execute?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sas, wait

I've got a bit of an issue with having my SAS sessions kick off, and subsequently wait for Python scripts to complete. I'm using Python for a Bag-of-Words analysis with some Sentiment analysis thrown in for flavor, and the script executes just fine, but SAS keeps going after kicking it off. This presents a problem, because the rest of the SAS program requires the results of the Python script to run properly.

I've tried to use the waitfor *all* command in SAS, but that doesn't seem to work for this particular issue.

Here's the code I'm executing in SAS:

```
%pScript_loc=path\pythonTester.py; /* LOCATION OF THE PROGRAM */
filename temp pipe "otherPath\python.exe &pScript."; /* LOCATION OF PYTHON EXECUTABLE */
data _null_;
infile temp;
input;
put _infile_;
run;

waitfor _all_;
```

This should make sure that the SAS program kicks the Python program off, but doesn't seem to be effective at making SAS wait for Python to do its thing.

Comment: Do you want SAS to pause for a specific amount of time? How will SAS know when the process is finished, is there a variable created with the status?

Comment: The python command will ultimately return a small dataset, but I'm not certain if I can import that into SAS from Python, or I'll have to use other means - like exporting it to excel in the python script, then importing it into SAS.

Either way, I'd want it to wait until that dataset / file is created, then bring the data in, and keep going.

Comment: I would recommend having python export to CSV (not Excel), and then using SAS to check the folder for the file. Once the file is found the rest of the process will proceed.

Comment: this would normally work - it seems python is running asynchronously, in which case there is no way for SAS to know.  Your best bet is to get your python script to call SAS when it finishes.

Comment: Does the Python script behave that way when you run it from the command line?  Sounds like a bug in the python script.  It is running in the background instead of the foreground.

Answer (score 2):

Try using the `x` command rather than a `data _null_` step. `xsync` is turned on by default in SAS, meaning that the OS will not return control to SAS until the Python script completes.

```
%let %pScript_loc=path\pythonTester.py;

x "otherPath\python.exe &pScript.";
```

You can also optionally use the `saspy` package and do everything from there, skipping the SAS editor altogether.

Answer (score 0):

`waitfor` is exclusive for `systask`
with filename it is a little bit different

```
filename x pipe 'dir';
data _NULL_;
  infile x DLM='$';
  length str $80;
  input str;
  put str;
run;
data _NULL_;
  infile x DLM='$';
  length str $80;
  input str;
  put str;
run;
```

each time a datastep access file the pipe is opened and read until closed. That means you can open the same time twice and there is no need to wait for end of program.